# Communication issue with Adam Module 4050

Tags: python-3.x, adam, data-acquisition

I'm trying to communicate with Adam Module 4050 via my PC COM Port. But its not even showing the device in Adam utility software. Green color light in device is continuously on.
[wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fb4D.jpg)
[Adam utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6BYG.jpg)

If any one who have worked with Adam Data acquisition module with python, Please guide me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.